# Run electron in dev mode

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I need to run an electron application in developer mode when I'm running locally and in production mode when the application is built, and I need to read this environment variable during the application.

I am using electron-builder in version 22.8.0 to build the application, and electron is in version 10.0.0.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, here is what I use to run `electron-reload` when in development. I think there are other, maybe better ways to do this now, but it has worked really well for me for a few years.

Define a var in the `start` script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "APP_DEV=true electron .",
  },
```

Then read it in `main.js`:

```
var isDev = process.env.APP_DEV ? (process.env.APP_DEV.trim() == 'true') : false;

if (isDev) {
    require('electron-reload')(__dirname);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already tried to change the value of APP_DEV just like you did in the start script, but when executing the script, Node accuses an error for not recognizing APP_DEV as a parameter. My start script was the same as in your example. I ended up solving my problem by creating a JS file that has a variable that indicates whether I am in development mode, functioning as an environment variable. It is not the way I want it, because I have to change the value of the variable manually before performing the build, but it managed to solve my problem.

Comment: I don't understand enough about Node `Process` to hazard a guess why it doesn't work for you – I got it working in order to use `electron-reload` and then just moved on to write more bugs ;-)  There are a lot of articles etc: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffcm&q=process.env&ia=web  – the "change-the-var-in-js-file" method is fragile since it's easy to forget to do (speaking from experience . . )

Comment: I dont really know this stuff but I got it to work on windows by changing it to this....
`"start": "set APP_DEV=true && electron ."`

Answer (score 1):

From the [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/) documentation:

[app.isPackaged](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appispackaged-readonly)

> A `boolean` property that returns `true` if the app is packaged, `false` otherwise. For many apps, this property can be used to distinguish development and production environments.